lidR: Creating tiles from a big .laz file
My problem:
I have big ALS .laz files and I want to calculate DSMs out of them.
For now, all my work starts with retiling the original .laz files into smaller ones. I began to hesitate when I read the manual and noticed the following:
*
Note that this function is not actually very useful because lidR manages everything (clipping, processing, buffering, ...) internally using the proper options. Thus, retiling may be useful for working in other software, for example, but not in lidR
Currently, I have used the following:
#Read the LAS catalog

ctg <- readLAScatalog("path/to/my/data/data.laz", select = "xyzrn")

#Set up options for retile

opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 250  # Define chunk size     
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 0   # Set buffer size between tiles    
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-drop_z_below 0"  # Exclude points with Z values below 0  
opt_select(ctg) <- "XYZ" # Consider only XYZ attributes for operations  
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "./tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"  # Define output file template

It creates tiles of 250x250m. Is there a better way of reducing the memory usage, or dividing my data before DSM creation?

If your goal is just to create a DSM:

Create a spatial index. This is important for chunking efficiently

lidR:::catalog_laxindex(ctg)


Compute the DSM by chunks. You can process by chunk in lidR. What the message says is that there is no reason to physically slit your point cloud in multiple LAS files.

opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 250  # Define chunk size       
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-drop_z_below 0"  # Exclude points with Z values below 0   
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "./tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"  # Define output
dsm = rasterize_canopy(ctg, 1, p2r())

Optionally, I suggest using the new lasR package which can handle big dataset much better. In this case the code would look like
library(lasR)
read = reader_las(filter = "-drop_z_below 0")
dsm = rasterize(1, "max", ofile = "path/to/dsm.tif")
pipeline = read + dsm
dsm = exec(pipeline, on = "path/to/my/data/data.laz")

In this specific case rasterize being streamable it uses virtually 0 memory.

Thank you for the answer! I supposed there might be a better way. I will try it, also considering changing the workflow entirely to lasR, as it seems quite straightforward.
